# How to add current time in an excel document for range of cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I would like to add current system time in an excel document when i should click on the cell.

- I want that it should only work for a range of cell not for the whole document.
- I have a code which is working for all the cell. But how to make it work only for particular range of cells?

*code*

```
 If Target.Address = ActiveCell.Address Then 
        Target = Format(Now, "ttttt")    
 End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict it to a range `Intersect` as below. When working with events you should:

- always disable Events so that the code doesnt re-call itself (a particular issue with the `Change` event)
- be clear if the `Target` applies to multiple cells or just a single cell.

code below uses `DoubleClick` event

*sheet module code*

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = Intersect(Target, Range("A1:a10"))
If rng1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Application.EnableEvents = False
rng1 = Format(Now, "ttttt")
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your code is in the `SelectionChange` event:

```
If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("RangeYouWantItToWorkFor") Is Nothing Then
        '...
```